# How to implement Observable.take using an FSharp.Control.Reactive observe computation?

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'm trying to understand how observe computations from FSharp.Control.Reactive work so I'm re-implementing the Observable.take combinator

This is my initial attempt:

```
let myTake (n : int) (source : IObservable<'a>) : IObservable<'a> =
    let rec go counter : IObservable<'a> =
        observe {
            let! v = source
            if counter < n
            then yield v
                 yield! go (counter + 1)
        }
    go 0
```

However, when I run the test below:

```
use subcription =
    subj
    |> myTake 2
    |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "next:%d")

subj.OnNext 1
subj.OnNext 2
subj.OnNext 3

waitForKey "my take"
```

I get the output:

```
next:1 
next:2 
next:2 
next:3 
next:3 
next:3
```

How can I fix this?

I also tried running myTake on an observable created with observable.ofSeq and it failed even worse i.e. it just produced the input sequence repeated several times. I assume it's related to the fact that ofSeq returns a cold observable but don't fully understand the behavior.

How can I make it work with cold observables too?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Tomas that the builder's native operations do not appear to support what you want.  However, my overall conclusion is a different than his - I don't see why observables are any more problematic for computation expressions than sequence are.

First of all, consider how you'd write `take` in a sequence expression.  There, `let!` isn't supported; you need to use a `for` loop instead.  But the analog to your code:

```
let rec go counter = seq {
    for v in source do
        if counter < n then
            yield v
            yield! go (counter + 1)
}
```

is just as broken for taking from a sequence as it is for taking from an observable: the counter is effectively telling you how many times to loop through a Cartesian product, which is not what you want.  One solution is to make the counter mutable and move it inside the expression (which then no longer needs to be recursive):

```
seq {
    let mutable counter = 0
    for v in source do
        if counter < n then
            yield v
            counter <- counter + 1
}
```

So that works for sequences, but what about for observables?  `observe` also supports `for` loops, but only for looping over a sequence rather than an observable.  However, we can remove this limitation by overloading the builder's `For` method:

```
type FSharp.Control.Reactive.Builders.ObservableBuilder with
    member __.For(o, f) =
        FSharp.Control.Reactive.Observable.bind f o
```

And now we can write `take` just as easily for observables as for sequences:

```
let myTake (n : int) (source : IObservable<'a>) : IObservable<'a> =
    observe {
        let mutable counter = 0
        for v in source do
            if counter < n then
                yield v
                counter <- counter + 1
    }
```

and you can verify that it works.

Comment: for is implemented in terms of bind, the same as let! is. Shouldn't it be possible to write the computation using let! ?

Comment: @vidi - you _can_, but I personally find the control flow much harder to understand (it's not nearly as obvious by inspection that `counter` could be updated more than once).

Comment: If you want to do so, just use `let! v = source` instead of the `for` loop and unindent the rest of the body.

Comment: Using myTake on a cold observable like this: [1;2;3;4]
        |> Observable.ofSeq
        |> myTake 2
        |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "myTake:%A") doesn't work. unless the counter increment is moved above the yield. Can you explain it?

Comment: @vidi - to me it seems possible that it's a bug in the builder, but I don't know enough about Rx to state that definitively.  If you modify the definition of the builder (source code [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive/blob/master/src/FSharp.Control.Reactive/Observable.fs)) to change the calls to `Empty` and `Return` to the overloads that don't take a scheduler, then everything appears to work as expected for both hot and cold observables.  However, there is presumably a reason that those overloads were used...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too familiar with the `observable` computation builder, but quick look at the source code shows that the `Bind` operation (which is behind `let!`) is [implemented using the Rx SelectMany operation](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive/blob/master/src/FSharp.Control.Reactive/Observable.fs#L17). The `SelectMany` operation will start the rest of the workflow for *every* occurrence of the event, so the behaviour you are seeing is the intended one.

The picture from [this article illustrates the behaviour well](http://www.thinqlinq.com/post.aspx/title/select-many-with-rx-and-rxjs):

[image]

I'm not sure what would be a good way of implementing `Observable.take` using the `observable` computation builder - frankly, I always thought that observables are not particularly good fit for F# computation expressions because the usual intuition that comes with computation expressions simply does not work for push-based observables.

I think observables work very well if you can get away with just composing the built-in operations, but they are not particularly nice when you need to implement your own custom primitives - and most of the time, I just use an F# agent to implement the logic and wrap it behind and observable.

Comment: Can you please explain better "the usual intuition that comes with computation expressions simply does not work for push-based observables"?

Comment: @vidi Not really, because the "intuition" is something that you gain by using a couple of computation expressions - I think the harmful thing in this case is that nobody expects that the rest of the computation is executed multiple times. I tried to characterize some of it in this paper though: http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/computation-zoo/

Comment: I'm not sure that's true; I think something very similar would happen with an analogous `seq` expression...

Comment: @kvb I'm not sure - sequences use `for` rather than `let!` so you can see that the body will be executed multiple times; even then, the body of `for` is only ever running once while for observables, the body would be started concurrently whenever an event happens.

Comment: It's interesting that the code posted by @kvb doesn't work with cold observables unless the increment is moved above the yield. That's not intuitive at all :(